# Valid use cases for `std::timed_mutex`?

Tags: c++, concurrency

In which situations would a [std::timed_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex) be preferred over a regular mutex?

The only use-case I can think of would be as a (IMO hackish) way to prevent deadlocks.

In what other situations would a `std::timed_mutex` be a good choice?

Answer (score 3):

That's a common design practice on Windows, where you'd use either `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` with a timeout value, specifying a time after which the wait should fail.

It's not used to work around deadlocks (that really wouldn't help, badly-threaded code is badly-threaded code).

Keeping in mind that Windows did not have the equivalent of Posix condition variables until the release of Windows Vista, an entirely different multi-threaded coding paradigm developed, which plays a part but is not the sole reason for the existence of timed mutexes.

Usage of timed waits isn't something you'd see in a basic example, but in a complex architecture you'll run across it more often than not. An example of where you *would* use a mutex is generally with some sort of producer-consumer architecture where the client must do something every x seconds, with the possibility of an "interrupt" in the form of an event being triggered. A simple pseudocode example:

```
//This code will run indefinitely, printing the value of 
//the variable x every 1 second until an interrupt is received
while(timed_wait(end_mutex, 1 second) != success)
    print(x)
```

Yes, this code could be rewritten as follows:

```
while(true){
   sleep(1 second)
   wait(mutex)
   done = globalDone
   unlock(mutex)

   if(done) break
   else print(x)
}
```

But the prior example is both cleaner and more responsive as it's not a sleep (i.e. any time the mutex becomes available, it'll stop).

Note that Linux has additional functions not part of the Posix standard to do timed waits on mutexes (`pthread_mutex_timedlock`, but I think it's now in the posix spec). So do sysv semaphores on OS X and BSD. It's a useful tool to have, if you are smart enough to only use it when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The best use-case for timed mutex wait is in operations that are only valid within a certain time, so they should fail in case of resource congestion.